# pages not calling in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view

i have three pages in my views folder index.php, about.php, and contact.php. and i have 2 link in index.php page now i want to call about.php and contact.php on that link. my index page is calling the below is my controller code.

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){

        $this->load->view('index');

    }
```

my index view is calling correctly..But i am failed to call other pages i am very new to codeignater. please someone help me

Comment: You should create a new Controller/method in order to load the other view pages; just like what you have done for the `index.php`

Comment: but what about my link how to call that view through link like

Comment: We don't call view files by hyperlinks, but the Controller/method as I  noted. Assuming `About::index()` controller/method for loading the about page, you could set the `href` of hyperlinks to  `index.php/about/index` (`about/index` or simply `about` if you have removed index.php from URLs).

Comment: @HashemQolami but how to call that through links

Comment: @HashemQolami <a href="about">About link</a> is it right for calling about.php

Comment: I'm not sure if you read my comments completely. Again, there's NO way to call a view file directly as the CI router parses the URI to load `Controller::method`. `<a href="about">` will work **only if** you create a new Controller called `About` and load its `about.php` view file within the `About::index()` method.

Comment: so explain me how i call that

Comment: I was trying to do so. However @Hammad's answer shows the correct way. Also consider my comments below his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your index.php you have to create two links i.e

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>blog/about">About</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>blog/contact">COntact</a>
```

And your controller code should look like this:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller{
function index(){

    $this->load->view('index');

}


function about(){

        $this->load->view('about');

    }

function contact(){

    $this->load->view('contact');

}
```

Comment: That's not a good idea to load *about* / *contact* pages within the `Blog` controller as they are completely irrelevant. Better to create new Controllers and use `$routes` to rewrite the URLs if it's needed.

Comment: And one more thing: Since we don't know whether the OP has removed `index.php` from URLs, it's better to use `site_url()` rather than `base_url()`.

Comment: Yes. It is a matter of choice whether to create separate controllers or use single one. Main purpose was to show him how to call new view/functions from views.

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php/';
```

First set in config.php
then:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home/sample">Sample</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home/about">About</a>
```

And Controller code like that:

class Home extends CI_Controller{
function index(){

```
$this->load->view('home');
```

}

function sample(){

```
    $this->load->view('sample');

}
```

function about(){

```
$this->load->view('about');
```

}